# How to create a jQuery function with option of a "sub-function"

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using a function drag and drop, and to avoid writing all the code needed to have this function I would use that example, that at the end of the main function, it would take that other function (confused middle) but it is something like this:

```js
$( window ).on( "mousemove", function(e) {
`enter code here`console.log( e.pageX );
})
```

in this example it performs the main function **mouseover on windows**, and based on the results of this function it performs another.
how to apply this on `jQuery` functions?

Comment: What is the value of `result`? How will it be passed to the function? Or should it be the result of the returned value?

Comment: Your `$.fn.test` function only has one listed parameter, `argument`, yet you are passing it two, an object an a function.

Comment: You return a callback in test for acccepting that result

Comment: argument = {Vala, ValA}. in the case = {1, 2};
que executa a função e faz 1 + 2 and return 3;
that is received by the "Subfunction" and makes an action with it.

Comment: I forgot to put there, but, **result** is the return of **$.fn.test**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the width of an element by which you are calling it .You should do something like this

check the following snippet

```js
var obj={"A":10,"B":20,"color":"red"};
$.fn.test = function(argument) {
    this.css( "width", argument.A+argument.B );
    this.css( "background", argument.color );
};
$(function(){
  $("#id1").test(obj);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
  id1
  </div>
```

Hope this helps